# Multiline EditText not scrolling vertically when virtual Keyboard is visible

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have EditText that is wrapping content as required; however, when the virtual Keyboard in visible on screen, I am unable to scroll the text vertically to display the lines on top that are hidden from view (e.g., first line when I am typing "android:lines"+1 line). When I hide the keyboard, it starts scrolling normally.

Layout File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/console_scroll"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:fillViewport="true">

  <LinearLayout 
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:padding="10dp"
      android:id="@+id/repl_container">

       <TextView
          android:id="@+id/console"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textIsSelectable="true"
          android:gravity="left|top"
          />

      <ProgressBar
          android:id="@+id/progress_running"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="right"
          android:indeterminate="true"
          android:visibility="invisible"
          style="Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
          />

       <EditText
          android:id="@+id/code_input"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions|textMultiLine"
          android:imeOptions="actionNone"
          android:imeActionLabel="@string/button_eval"
          android:hint="@string/input_code_hint"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
          android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
          android:scrollHorizontally="false"
          android:lines="5"
          android:maxLines="100"
          />

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/button_eval"
          android:text="@string/button_evaluate"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
          android:gravity="center"
          />

  </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I am observing this on KK 4.4.4, if it matters. Any pointers as to why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your manifest.xml, add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"` under your activity tag.

**LIKE THIS:**

```
<activity android:name="......"
      .....
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize">
  ......
/>
```